# How to get collection from other collection in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I making report for my Magento 2 site. My code as below and the result of orderCollection as image.

```
$sale_order_item_table = $this->_resource->getTableName('sales_order_item');

    $catalog_category_product_table = $this->_resource->getTableName('catalog_category_product');

    $catalog_category_entity_text_table = $this->_resource->getTableName('catalog_category_entity_text');

    $catalog_category_entity_varchar_table = $this->_resource->getTableName('catalog_category_entity_varchar');

    $orderCollection = $this->_salesOrderCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id');
        //->addFieldToFilter('status', 'complete');

    $orderCollection->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(
            ['soi' => $sale_order_item_table],
            "main_table.entity_id = soi.order_id",
            [
                'item_id' => 'soi.item_id',
                'order_id' => 'soi.order_id',
                'product_id' => 'soi.product_id',
                'base_row_total' => 'soi.base_row_total',
                'base_discount_amount' => "soi.base_discount_amount"
            ]
        )
        ->join(
            ['ccp' => $catalog_category_product_table],
            "soi.product_id = ccp.product_id",
            [
                'category_id' => 'ccp.category_id'
            ]
        )
        ->join(
            ['ccet' => $catalog_category_entity_text_table],
            "ccp.category_id = ccet.entity_id",
            [
                'kpt_id' => 'ccet.value'
            ]
        )
        ->join(
            ['ccev' => $catalog_category_entity_varchar_table],
            "ccet.entity_id = ccev.entity_id",
            [
                'category_name' => "ccev.value"
            ]
        )
        ->where("ccev.attribute_id = 45 AND ccev.store_id = 1 AND ccet.value IS NOT NULL")
        ->group("kpt_id");

    $saleOrderData = $orderCollection->getData();

    echo $orderCollection->getSelect();
    die;
```

The result image:
[image]

I need count number of item, sum base_row_total, sum base_discount_amount and group by category_id or group by kpt_id (kpt_id is value in catalog_category_entity_text table).

I think to get collection from $orderCollection->getSelect() to do that.

I want expect result:
[image]

Please help me, How to do that?
Thanks & Best regards,
BienHV

Answer (score 0):

I was fixed by this code:

```
$sale_order_item_table = $this->_resource->getTableName('sales_order_item');

        $catalog_category_product_table = $this->_resource->getTableName('catalog_category_product');

        $catalog_category_entity_text_table = $this->_resource->getTableName('catalog_category_entity_text');

        $catalog_category_entity_varchar_table = $this->_resource->getTableName('catalog_category_entity_varchar');

        $orderCollection = $this->_salesOrderCollectionFactory->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id');
            //->addFieldToFilter('status', 'complete');

        $orderCollection->getSelect()
            ->joinRight(
                ['soi' => $sale_order_item_table],
                "main_table.entity_id = soi.order_id",
                [
                    'total_orders' => 'count(distinct soi.order_id)',
                    'total_items' => 'count(soi.item_id)',
                    'base_row_total' => 'sum(soi.base_row_total)',
                    'base_discount_amount' => "sum(soi.base_discount_amount)",
                    'base_amount_refunded' => "sum(soi.base_amount_refunded)"
                ]
            )
            ->joinLeft(
                ['ccp' => $catalog_category_product_table],
                "soi.product_id = ccp.product_id",
                [
                    'category_id' => 'ccp.category_id'
                ]
            )
            ->join(
                ['ccet' => $catalog_category_entity_text_table],
                "ccp.category_id = ccet.entity_id",
                [
                    'kpt_id' => 'ccet.value'
                ]
            )
            ->join(
                ['ccev' => $catalog_category_entity_varchar_table],
                "ccet.entity_id = ccev.entity_id",
                [
                    'category_name' => "ccev.value"
                ]
            )
            ->where("ccev.attribute_id = 45 AND ccev.store_id = 1 AND ccet.value IS NOT NULL")
            ->group("kpt_id")
            ->order('kpt_id DESC');

        $saleOrderData = $orderCollection->getData();
```